# How to remove duplicate in combobox with bindingsource in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Please help me to remove duplicate in my combobox that I linked with bindimgsource from table in my database. I used many codes like:

```
  Dim TextLines = CboReRegNo.Text.Split(New String() {vbNewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim totalcount = TextLines.Length
    Dim noduplicate = TextLines.Distinct().Count()
    Dim remove = totalcount - noduplicate
    CboReRegNo.Text = String.Join(vbNewLine, TextLines.Distinct.ToArray())
```

and

```
    For i As Int16 = 0 To Me.CboReRegNo.Items.Count - 2
        For j As Int16 = Me.CboReRegNo.Items.Count - 1 To i + 1 Step -1
            If Me.CboReRegNo.Items(i).ToString = Me.CboReRegNo.Items(i).ToString Then
                Me.CboReRegNo.Items.RemoveAt(j)
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

and they didn't work, I assume it may be because it is with bindingsource. I want see only single record not duplicate on the combobox. Please help me solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show the query you are using to fetch the records... Also you are setting the text, you want to set the datasource which binds to your data...

Comment: I just used bindingsource to my combobox, when I run, it gives me displayed value.

Comment: I dont see where you are binding anything.

Comment: I am sorry I mean I clicked on the combobox then clicked the arrow and assigned my binding source.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible for databind combobox, but you can use another method.

Read data from Dataset DataTable, Export it to TEMPORARY TextFile, remove any duplicates and then add back to combobox.

**Here's the code**, Replce text in **[ ]** with your data

```
'[READ LINES FROM DATABASE COLUMN & EXPORT TO TEMP TEXTFILE] 
Dim table As DataTable = [YOUR_DATASET].[YOUR_DATATABLE_NAME]
        Dim result = New StringBuilder()
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            For i As Integer = 1 To table.Columns.Count - 1 '[COLUMN_NUMBER i.e 1 = column 2]
                result.Append(row(i).ToString())
                result.Append(If(i = table.Columns.Count - 1, vbLf, ","))
            Next
            result.AppendLine()
        Next
        Dim objWriter As New StreamWriter("D:\test.txt", False) ' [CREATE TEMP FILE AND THEN DELETE IT IN LAST]
        objWriter.WriteLine(result.ToString())
        objWriter.Close()
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'[REMOVE EMPTY LINES if ANY & ADD TEXT FROM FILE TO COMBOBOX]
        Dim newlines As New List(Of String (IO.File.ReadAllLines("D:\test.txt"))
        newlines.RemoveAll(Function(s) s.Trim = "")
        ComboBox2.Items.AddRange(newlines.ToArray)
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 '[REMOVE DUPLICATES FROM COMBOBOX]
        Dim list As New List(Of Object)()
        For Each o As Object In ComboBox2.Items
            If Not list.Contains(o) Then
                list.Add(o)
            End If
        Next
        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox2.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray())
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'[DELETE TEMP FILE]
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("D:/test.txt")
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help Ali, i will try it.  Thanks